# Error reading many files in a subfolder

Tags: c++

I have a problem with read file in the subfolder. I have about 6000 different files in the difference folders. And I will read each file. But if I read about 2000 files, then application is not problem. When I read 6000 files which mean whole subfolders. The application will display problem "can not open file.". But if I only access the folder that is not open, then application is not problem. I don't know what is happen? I think maybe I read many files and memory not enough. Can you edit help me?

```
//This is code to access subforder

static int
find_directory(
        const char *dirname)
{

    DIR *dir;
    char buffer[PATH_MAX + 2];
    char *p = buffer;
    const char *src;
    const char* folder_dir;
    char *end = &buffer[PATH_MAX];
    int ok;

    /* Copy directory name to buffer */
    src = dirname;

    printf("src=%s\n",src);
    while (p < end  &&  *src != '\0') {
        *p++ = *src++;
    }
    *p = '\0';

    /* Open directory stream */
    dir = opendir (dirname);
    if (dir != NULL) {
        struct dirent *ent;

        /* Print all files and directories within the directory */
        while ((ent = readdir (dir)) != NULL) {
            char *q = p;
            char c;

            /* Get final character of directory name */
            if (buffer < q) {
                c = q[-1];
            } else {
                c = ':';
            }

            /* Append directory separator if not already there */
            if (c != ':'  &&  c != '/'  &&  c != '\\') {
                *q++ = '/';
            }

            /* Append file name */
            src = ent->d_name;
            while (q < end  &&  *src != '\0') {
                *q++ = *src++;
            }
            *q = '\0';

            /* Decide what to do with the directory entry */
            switch (ent->d_type) {
                case DT_REG:
                    /* Output file name with directory */
                    {
                        printf ("FILE=%s\n", buffer);
                        OFBool check= readfile(buffer)
                    }
                    break;

                case DT_DIR:
                    /* Scan sub-directory recursively */
                    if (strcmp (ent->d_name, ".") != 0  
                            &&  strcmp (ent->d_name, "..") != 0) {

                        find_directory (buffer,opts);


                    }
                    break;

                default:
                    /* Do not device entries */
                    /*NOP*/;
            }

        }

        closedir (dir);
        ok = 1;

    } else {
        /* Could not open directory */
        printf ("Cannot open directory %s\n", dirname);
        ok = 0;
    }

    return ok;
}
OFBool readfile(const char* filepath)
{
    FILE *f=NULL; 
    OFBool ok = OFFalse;
    if( ( f = fopen( filepath, "rb" ) ) == NULL ) // checks to see if file  exists
    {
        ok = OFFalse;
        cout<<"can not read file"<<filepath<<endl;
        return ok; 
    }
    else
    {
        ok = true;
        cout<<" reading OK"<<endl;
        fclose(f); 
        return ok; 
    }

}
```

Comment: That's a lot of code. You could narrow it down a lot.

Comment: Why do you implement your own `strcpy` and `strcat`?

Comment: Better still, how is this C++?

Comment: Also, you check in your copying and concatenation that you don't go over `end`, but still recurse even when the buffer is full (with the wrong path), and you also add the `.` and `..` directories to the path even if you don't recurse into them.

Comment: Sorry. The code to get file name that is got from example of drient.h libary. I don't edit it. I only add read function to read the file name. Do you have a better code to read file in sub-folder?

Comment: Please don't mix C and C++ and call the result C.

Comment: @Angew It uses `std::cout`?

Comment: @unwind I know that almost all C is actually valid C++, but it's misused C++. The above code uses C thinking and C tools where C++ has more idiomatic (and easier to use) alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
/*
 * Recursively walk though a directory tree.
 *
 * Arguments:
 *     path   - The root directory to start from
 *     hidden - If non-zero, include hidden files and directories
 */
void recurse_directory(const char *path, const int hidden)
{
    DIR *dir = opendir(path);
    if (dir == NULL)
    {
        perror("opendir");
        return;
    }

    struct dirent *ent;

    while ((ent = readdir(dir)) != NULL)
    {
        if (ent->d_type == DT_DIR)
        {
            if (strcmp(ent->d_name, ".") != 0 &&
                strcmp(ent->d_name, "..") != 0 &&
                (ent->d_name[0] != '.' || hidden))
            {
                char *newpath = malloc(strlen(path) + 1 + strlen(ent->d_name) + 1);
                strcpy(newpath, path);
                strcat(newpath, "/");
                strcat(newpath, ent->d_name);

                recurse_directory(newpath, hidden);

                free(newpath);
            }
        }
        else if (ent->d_type == DT_REG)
        {
            if (ent->d_name[0] != '.' || hidden)
            {
                char *newpath = malloc(strlen(path) + 1 + strlen(ent->d_name) + 1);
                strcpy(newpath, path);
                strcat(newpath, "/");
                strcat(newpath, ent->d_name);

                printf("File %s\n", newpath);
                /* readfile(newpath); */

                free(newpath);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Too add to the answer from Joachim Pileborg. If you are working with a large number of sub-directories you'd need to add **closedir()** call after while loop. This is because there is a limit on the number of directories you can have open at one time. The above example will work fine when working with a small folder, but when working with 2000+ sub-folders you'd need to close the directory before opening another.

```
/*
* Recursively walk though a directory tree.
*
* Arguments:
*     path   - The root directory to start from
*     hidden - If non-zero, include hidden files and directories
*/
void recurse_directory(const char *path, const int hidden)
{
    DIR *dir = opendir(path);
    if (dir == NULL)
{
    perror("opendir");
    return;
}

struct dirent *ent;

while ((ent = readdir(dir)) != NULL)
{
    if (ent->d_type == DT_DIR)
    {
        if (strcmp(ent->d_name, ".") != 0 &&
            strcmp(ent->d_name, "..") != 0 &&
            (ent->d_name[0] != '.' || hidden))
        {
            char *newpath = malloc(strlen(path) + 1 + strlen(ent->d_name) + 1);
            strcpy(newpath, path);
            strcat(newpath, "/");
            strcat(newpath, ent->d_name);

            recurse_directory(newpath, hidden);

            free(newpath);
        }
    }
    else if (ent->d_type == DT_REG)
    {
        if (ent->d_name[0] != '.' || hidden)
        {
            char *newpath = malloc(strlen(path) + 1 + strlen(ent->d_name) + 1);
            strcpy(newpath, path);
            strcat(newpath, "/");
            strcat(newpath, ent->d_name);

            printf("File %s\n", newpath);
            /* readfile(newpath); */

            free(newpath);
        }
      }
   }
      closedir(dir); /* Add this <--- */
}
```